# Javascript $ is not defined with document.ready

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, and I'm getting a "$ is not defined" result with the document.ready script not working correctly. I've looked up many different questions of this online, and I cannot figure it out.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready (function() {
        $( "body>[data-role='panel']" ).panel();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why have you included 3 jQuery sources?

Comment: You shouldn't load 3 copies of jquery.

Comment: LOL... Not Enough jQuery!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "body>[data-role='panel']" ).panel();
    });
</script>
```